# Roots, multivariable functions and Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, variational-calculus

Let

$f(x,y)=(10 x^2 + 4 x y - 2 x + 4 y^2 - 4 y + 1)^2 (32 x^2 - 64 x y + 24 x + 40 y^2 - 28 y + 5)^2$

```
(10 x^2 + 4 x y - 2 x + 4 y^2 - 4 y + 1)^2 *
 (32 x^2 - 64 x y + 24 x + 40 y^2 - 28 y + 5)^2
```

be a multivariable function with two different real solutions $\displaystyle \left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)=(\frac{-1}{8},\frac{1}{4})$ and $\displaystyle(x_{1},x_{2})=(0,\frac{1}{2})$.

How may I obtain the same solutions by employing Mathematica?

Comment: Doesn't your polynomial have infinitely many solutions? (Assuming "solution" = root)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you mean ***real*** roots?:

```
Reduce[(10 x^2 + 4 x y - 2 x + 4 y^2 - 4 y + 1)^2 (32 x^2 - 64 x y + 
      24 x + 40 y^2 - 28 y + 5)^2 == 0, {x, y}, Reals]

(*  (x == -(1/8) && y == 1/4) || (x == 0 && y == 1/2)  *)
```

or

```
Solve[(10 x^2 + 4 x y - 2 x + 4 y^2 - 4 y + 1)^2 (32 x^2 - 64 x y + 
      24 x + 40 y^2 - 28 y + 5)^2 == 0, {x, y}, Reals]

(*  {{x -> -(1/8), y -> 1/4}, {x -> 0, y -> 1/2}}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Michael E2 for commenting. That is exactly what I was searching for. In order to find integer solutions, should I replace "Reals" for "Integers"?

Comment: @ViniciusHolmes Yes, replace `Reals` with `Integers`, but sometimes, if there are finitely many real solutions, it is quicker to find all of them and filter for the integer ones.  One might also specify `Solve[eq && Element[{x, y}, Integers], {x, y}, Reals]`. The algorithms that may be applied when you change the domain  (e.g. `Reals`) are different, and thus it is not always straightforward what to recommend.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael E2!

Comment: @ViniciusHolmes This works, too, on your problem: `Solve[eq, {x, y}, Rationals]` -- forgot to try it earlier :)

Answer (score 2):

The roots of a polynomial of 2 variables are a 1D region. That is, you will get equations as a result. E.g.:

```
f[X_, Y_] = (10 x^2 + 4 x y \[Minus] 2 x + 4 y^2 \[Minus] 4 y + 
      1)^2 (32 x^2 \[Minus] 64 x y + 24 x + 40 y^2 \[Minus] 28 y + 
      5)^2;
sol=Reduce[f[x, y] == 0, {x, y}]
```

(*[image]*)

We get 4 different solutions.

If we restrict x to the region: -1..1 we may plot y[x] as complex functions with real and imaginary parts:

```
ReImPlot[Evaluate[{y /. #}], {x, -1, 1}] & /@ {ToRules[sol]}
```

[image]